# Rosserial_arduino: Lost sync with device, restarting

Tags: arduino, rosserial

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to get a service server running on an Arduino.  The code compiles, and I know (from debugging with an Arduino-attached LED) that the code to advertise the services is executed and that the sketch's loop() function executes (at about a 1 second interval).  However, when I start rosserial_python, I get:

```
$ rosrun rosserial_python serial_node.py /dev/ttyUSB0
[INFO] [WallTime: 1323211562.638344] ROS Serial Python Node
[INFO] [WallTime: 1323211562.649185] Connected on /dev/ttyUSB0 at 57600 baud
[ERROR] [WallTime: 1323211577.655402] Lost sync with device, restarting...
[ERROR] [WallTime: 1323211592.663968] Lost sync with device, restarting...
```

The sketch initializes the serial port to 57600, rosserial_python's default baud rate.

Any suggestion on why I'm not getting or maintaining sync?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12243/rosserial_arduino:--lost-sync-with-device,-restarting.../) by [mcsmith](https://answers.ros.org/users/1313/mcsmith/) on ROS Answers with karma: 66 on 2011-12-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The problem was that the service objects were incorrectly declared with setup(), not globally.  They would go out of scope prematurely, resulting in the symptoms described above.

---

Originally posted by [mcsmith](https://answers.ros.org/users/1313/mcsmith/) with karma: 66 on 2011-12-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This happened to me a lot, and 90% of the time turned out to be because I was trying to push too much data over the line. For example, the ros_lib ADC example for me will lose sync constantly until I added a delay in the loop (10Hz works reliably for me).

---

Originally posted by [Elucidation](https://answers.ros.org/users/11291/elucidation/) with karma: 13 on 2014-03-13

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1